# HTML table with resizable columns using percentage width

Tags: javascript, html-table, percentage, resizable

There are plenty solutions for resizable tables out there. But all of them have in common that they are using pixel widths and not percentage widths.

In my use case my tables col widths need to be with a percentage width or at least set to an percentage width after the resize action. My implemented solution is buggy when starting to resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/bg843pkt/24/

```
var thElm;
var startOffset;

var eG;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("table th"),
  function (th) {
    th.style.position = 'relative';

    var grip = document.createElement('div');
    grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    grip.style.top = 0;
    grip.style.right = 0;
    grip.style.bottom = 0;
    grip.style.width = '5px';
    grip.style.position = 'absolute';
    grip.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
    grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        thElm = th;
        startOffset = th.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
    });

    th.appendChild(grip);
  });

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (thElm) {
    thElm.style.width = startOffset + e.pageX + '%';
    eG = e.pageX;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thElm = undefined;
});
```

[How it acts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAeO2.gif)

[How it should act](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O9Qz.gif)

Can anyone tell me how i can implement this functionality with percentage width without any buggy behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Would you please elaborate on the concept of "buggy"? Exactly what is it doing that is wrong compared to what you want it to do...

Comment: @elbrant I added two gifs which show what i mean with buggy (its hard to describe for me) and how it should act like.

Comment: its most likely because you are getting your pos from TD width, not its parents (TR or Table). So it scales regarding the td. for example if your mouse is on 40% of TD, it thinks its on 40% of the tr(table).

Comment: I got it a little less buggy but still not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln280eqc/8/

Answer (score 2):

I created a working example but it is using an older jQuery Version.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln280eqc/17/

```
    $("table").resizableColumns();
```

Source: https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns

Comment: Is there a way to get the size of every column in percentage?

Answer (score 0):

I created table with column resize, the initial width is percentage.
When you resize the column, you can get the PX of the column first and then convert it to percentage according to the width of the whole table.
https://biechao.github.io/2019/11/20/storybook-static/?path=/story/table--resizable-column-table